# How to insert Text into the currently focused textbox in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have 4 text boxes and when the user clicks a button i wish to insert the relevant text and move on to the next text box and insert the next text in that box. i have got some distance my code so far is.

```
Time1Btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Time1Btn);
Time2Btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Time2Btn);
Time1HrEB = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Time1HrEB);  // i would guess this would be replaced

Time1Btn.setOnClickListener(MyOnClickListener);
Time2Btn.setOnClickListener(MyOnClickListener);

private View.OnClickListener MyOnClickListener = new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
   Button b = (Button)v;
   EditText e = (EditText).getCurrentFocus(); // attemt of what to do

   String buttonText = b.getText().toString();
   e.setText(buttonText); // this is the line i wish to replace.
   int id = getCurrentFocus().getNextFocusRightId();

       findViewById(id).requestFocus();
      }
};
```

my layout file is.

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/Time1HrEB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxWidth="30dp"
            android:minWidth="30dp"
            android:nextFocusRight="@+id/Time2HrEB"
          >
</EditText>

<EditText
            android:id="@+id/Time2HrEB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:minWidth="30dp"
             />
etc...
```

any ideas... i have tryed some things...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are close

```
View et = getCurrentFocus()
EditText e = (EditText) et;
e.setText(buttonText);
```

give it a try and let me know.